# Tracking Completion of an Azure WebJob Workflow when handled by hundreds of subjobs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I have a file processing workflow that I want to handle using Azure Webjobs.  There is a single incoming PDF that could be 1 page or a thousand pages.  That file is saved to blob storage, and a message is queued to start processing.  The first webjob takes the queue message and the file and breaks the PDF into individual pages, writes a DB record for the page, rasterizing them to images.  Then for each page, it saves the image to blob storage and queues a new message (different queue) for the page processor.  That second webjob processes the individual page images (reads a barcode, crops, more DB writes, etc).

Since the pages will be processed in parallel (multiple jobs per machine and multiple machines in the web app group), I am trying to devise the best way to figure out when the entire file has finished processing.  Even though I write the status of each page to it's DB record, I have encountered race conditions where the final pages effectively finish simultaneously and there is really not "last page" that my script can check for.  Do I need some outside process to check the status (querying that every page has a "finished" flag)?  Thoughts on how this might be best accomplished would be appreciated.

Comment: Your idea seems to be good. After processing each page, you update the page status and check if there is more to process. If not you've done ^^

Comment: Yes, but checking if there is more work to do is complex when using Azure queues.  You can't query an Azure Queue, so I have no way of knowing what work is left for a specific file, and even then the queue could be empty but the webjobs could still be working on pages.  It seems the only solution is to have a 3rd queue with a process that checks for all page statuses in the DB and then marks it complete after the fact.  But this injects some delay.

Comment: No you need to check your record in the db. For a specific job, you check if all the pages have been processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to build a batch process system for handling PDFs.

For some simple & single processing, using Azure WebJobs with Azure Storage is a good choice, but seems to be not suitable for your current needs.

Per my experience, my suggestion is that you can try to use [Azure Batch Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-technical-overview/) to build the batch system which you can monitor the status of jobs. Please refer to the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-dotnet-get-started/) to know how to get started. Meanwhile, there is a offical [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/) project on GitHub and a GUI tool called [`Azure Batch Explorer`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/BatchExplorer) which you can follow the [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowshpc/2015/01/20/azure-batch-explorer-sample-walkthrough/) to learn how to use.

Comment: Thanks.  I was aware that Batch existed, but I had not really looked at it for this particular problem.  I will read through the docs and samples.